# Автозапуск сервисов

Tags: linux, debian, автозапуск, gnu-screen

Нужно сделать при старте машины на Debian, выполнение screen -S name1 и в этом скрине запуск скрипта по пути cd ~/Scripts/ ./start.sh name1 и таких несколько команд вместо name1 будет name2 и т.д. соответственно. То есть нужно сделать одновременный запуск нескольких скринов и в каждом скрине определенную команду.

Подскажите пожалуйста как именно нужно вписать в rc.local или другим способов.

Comment: Вам обязательно именно screen? Уточните вашу задачу — вам обязательно всегда иметь под рукой интерактивные консоли со всеми вашими серверами, или вам лишь нужно, чтобы серверы запустились и работали в фоне?

Comment: Нужно именно screen

Comment: `screen -d -m -S name /путь/к/запускаемому/скрипту` и да, положить куда нибудь в rc.local  А `cd ~/Scripts/` положите лучше внутрь запускаемого скрипта. и лучше путь целиком писать. rc.local под рутом работает `~` у вас к руту домой ведет ?

Comment: Получается мне нужно написать несколько строк
screen -d -m -S name1 /root/Scripts/start.sh name1
screen -d -m -S name2 /root/Scripts/start.sh name2